# Is there a way to customize the items to approve list on the home page

Tags: administration, home-page-component

I just want to see if its possible customize the items to approve [image: the items to approve] list on the homepage. I actually want to show submitter instead of most recent approver. Is this possible?

Another possibility i am exploring would be to have an option to bulk approve ie to have a checkbox against each item to approve record and have a button to bulk approve.

I can see that we have this option on the manage all button, is there a way to have it on the home screen itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you go to the Home page setup `My Name->Setup->App Setup->Customize->Home` you will see options for Home Page Components, Layouts and Custom Links. On the Components page the only standard components that can be edited are `Messages & Alerts` and `Custom Links`. If you go to the Page Layouts you will see that your only options are which to components to include, again without customization.

An alternative might be a custom Visualforce page that you set as the default for your users.

Comment: I thought so too.. Thanks for confirming... Gonna wait for some more time before i accept the answer, just in case someone with a magic wand has a workaround ;)

Comment: Can we do this now or is it still not possible?

Comment: @User2529 still not possible.

Comment: @Prady - any update?